# Adding easing on requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, easing

I need to reproduce the same effect as here: http://www.chanel.com/fr_FR/mode/haute-couture.html = a swipe effect on mouse move event.

I just need some help on the animation part.

```
    function frame() {
      $('.images-gallery').css({
        'transform': 'translateX('+ -mouseXPerc +'%)'
      });
      requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    $(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
      mouseXPerc = e.pageX/containerWidth*100;

    });
```

Here's what I've done so far. **It works as supposed, but as you can imagine, it's pretty raw, I need some easing in that**. How can I edit my `frame() function` to get something smoother ?

Edit : I can't use CSS transition / animation as I change the value on requestAnimationFrame (each 1/30 sec).

Answer (score 17):

I think I've found an answer for you. It's based on [this library](https://github.com/component/ease)

First, I would just grab a function from that site

```
function inOutQuad(n){
    n *= 2;
    if (n < 1) return 0.5 * n * n;
    return - 0.5 * (--n * (n - 2) - 1);
};
```

Then, I would use a modified form of the example code, something like this

```
function startAnimation(domEl){
    var stop = false;

    // animating x (margin-left) from 20 to 300, for example
    var startx = 20;
    var destx = 300;
    var duration = 1000;
    var start = null;
    var end = null;

    function startAnim(timeStamp) {
        start = timeStamp;
        end = start + duration;
        draw(timeStamp);
    }

    function draw(now) {
        if (stop) return;
        if (now - start >= duration) stop = true;
        var p = (now - start) / duration;
        val = inOutQuad(p);
        var x = startx + (destx - startx) * val;
        $(domEl).css('margin-left', `${x}px`);
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(startAnim);
}
```

I might change how 'stop' is calculated, I might write something to ensure that it ends on `destx`, etc, but that's the basic format

Showing it in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k3umzr1/1/)

I'm actually kinda proud of this one. I've been wanting to figure this out for a while. Glad I had a reason to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `ease` function and use it inside your `frame` function:

```
var ease = function() {
    var x = 0;
    return function(x_new) {
        x = (x_new+x)*.5;
        return x;
    }
}();

function frame() {
  $('.images-gallery').css({
    'transform': 'translateX('+ -ease(mouseXPerc) +'%)'
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(frame);
}

requestAnimationFrame(frame);
$(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
  mouseXPerc = e.pageX/containerWidth*100;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [fast-ease.js](https://github.com/caracal7/fast-ease) but without ability to interrupt animation

```js
function inOutQuad(n){
    n *= 2;
    if (n < 1) return 0.5 * n * n;
    return - 0.5 * (--n * (n - 2) - 1);
};

function animate(callback, ease, duration, from, to) {
    var id;
    var start = performance.now();
    var end = start + duration;
    function frame(now) {
        var delta = now - start;
        if (delta >= duration) return cancelAnimationFrame(id);
        callback(from + (to - from) * ease(delta / duration));
        id = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
    }
    id = requestAnimationFrame(frame);
};
```