# RequestAnimationFrame - should I use the DOMHighResTimeStamp parameter?

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

I've been trying to research how to use requestAnimationFrame and I've ended up very confused.

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), if you have an animation function called 'step' that you call with `requestAnimationFrame(step)`, `step` accepts an argument that is a number of milliseconds, a DOMHighResTimeStamp argument.

And yet every single example I've seen online of how to use requestAnimationFrame does not use this argument. Some examples insist that you can assume the `step` function will run 60 times a second, and so they don't use any `time` concepts at all. Others get their own "number of milliseconds" separate from the argument, by using `new Date();` - I suppose it's easy enough to modify these examples to use the argument instead.

Is it ok to assume the function will run 60 times a second? Seems...unwise to me. Mozilla says *"The number of callbacks is usually 60 times per second, but will generally match the display refresh rate in most web browsers as per W3C recommendation"*, which doesn't make me comfortable with that assumption. Is there a reason why people are using their own `new Date()` way of getting milliseconds rather than using the argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there were some other answers and comments before but for some reason people removed them. I ended up figuring out how to use the timestamp appropriately and posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604409/1959054)

I'll copy the answer over:

---

I think I've found an answer for you. It's based on [this library](https://github.com/component/ease)

First, I would just grab a function from that site

```
function inOutQuad(n){
    n *= 2;
    if (n < 1) return 0.5 * n * n;
    return - 0.5 * (--n * (n - 2) - 1);
};
```

Then, I would use a modified form of the example code, something like this

```
function startAnimation(domEl){
    var stop = false;

    // animating x (margin-left) from 20 to 300, for example
    var startx = 20;
    var destx = 300;
    var duration = 1000;
    var start = null;
    var end = null;

    function startAnim(timeStamp) {
        start = timeStamp;
        end = start + duration;
        draw(timeStamp);
    }

    function draw(now) {
        if (stop) return;
        if (now - start >= duration) stop = true;
        var p = (now - start) / duration;
        val = inOutQuad(p);
        var x = startx + (destx - startx) * val;
        $(domEl).css('margin-left', `${x}px`);
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(startAnim);
}
```

I might change how 'stop' is calculated, I might write something to ensure that it ends on `destx`, etc, but that's the basic format

Showing it in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k3umzr1/1/)

I'm actually kinda proud of this one. I've been wanting to figure this out for a while. Glad I had a reason to.